# prevent auto tag generate in javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Why does

```
theMenuSection.innerHTML='<ul>';
alert(theMenuSection.innerHTML);
```

Produce `<ul> </ul>` just i have the opening  tag.can i get `<ul>` from innerHTML tag

thanks

Comment: If you are trying to construct a menu, you should construct the html menu at the start and set innerHTML only once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Typically (*this is per-browser dependent*) when you interact with the DOM, or utilize innerHTML (*which interacts with the DOM*), you will see the browsers "corrected" interpretation of what the HTML should look like.  Same reason why Firefox auto-injects "thead" elements into tables when your source code doesn't have any of that.  The browser is trying to infer 'correct' HTML from what it sees.